# linked list and objects issue

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a linked list using objects.  I get this error msg when I compile the code:

```
Person.java:49: error: constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types;
      Node newNode = new Node(last, first, age);
```

Can anyone kindly give me a hand? why is this happening? Thank you. 
Here is the code:

```
    class Person{

private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private int age;

   public Person(String last, String first, int a){
      lastName=last;
      firstName=first;
      age=a;
   } 

   public void displayPerson(){
      System.out.println("Last Name: "+lastName);
      System.out.println("First name"+firstName);
      System.out.println("Age: "+age);
   }

   public String getLast(){
      return lastName;                                                                                                             
   }
}

class Node
{
   public Person data; 
   public Node next; 

   public Node(Person d)
   {
      data = d; 
   }

}
class LinkList
{
   private Node first;

   public  LinkList()
   {
      first = null;
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (first==null);
   }
   public void insertFirst(String last, String first, int age)
   {
      Node newNode = new Node(last, first, age);
      newNode.next = first;
      first = newNode;
   }
   public Node deleteFirst(String last, String first, int age)
   {
      Node temp = first;
      first = first.next;
      return temp;
   }
   public void displayList()
   {
      System.out.print("Linked List (first -->last): ");
      Node current = first;
      while(current != null)
      {
         current.displayPerson();
         current = current.next;
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have a node constructor which takes `string, string, int`? Also `first = newNode;` is ambiguous, I think you meant to write something like `this.first = newNode;`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Node newNode = new Node(last, first, age);
```

does not compile since the Node class does not have a constructor with three parameters of these types. It seems that you want

```
Node newNode = new Node(new Person(last, first, age));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node newNode = new Node(last, first, age);`

Node doesn't have a constructor that takes 3 arguments.

I'm assuming you meant to create a `Person` object first and then pass that to the `Node` constructor, such as `new Node(new Person(last, first, age))`

Answer (score 0):

I see some other errors in your code, for example:

- on the insertFirst method, your String first parameter is hiding your Node first attribute. You should rename your parameter to avoid this
- On your displayList method yo have current.displayPerson (), I think you want to current.data.displayPerson ()

Hope this helps :)
Alberto